# Distribution of the square root of the sum of two i.i.d. random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, density-function

For the random variable $Z=\sqrt{U}=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two i.i.d. random variables with pdf

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-x^2}}\,,\quad x\in[-1,1]$$

The probability density functions of $X$ and $X^2$ are easy to calculate, but the pdf of $U$ is difficult to calculate since the integral is hard.
I would like to get the expectation and variance of $Z$. Is there any way to estimate the expectation and variance as accurate as possible? Like Taylor expansion or something else?

Comment: What is the PDF of $X$?

Comment: Hi: You didn't say how $X$ and $Y$ are distributed.

Comment: The question in the title does not exactly match the question the body.

Comment: Sorrry, I have updated it.

Comment: If all you need is a numerical estimate of the mean and variance, using a computer to randomly generate a large number of values from $Z$ and estimating the mean/variance from them may work.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. But I would like to find an universal solution to this question in the form of formula.

Comment: You can in general compute the expectation value of a two variable function of i.i.d. random variables as $E[g(x,y)] =\int \int g(x,y) f_X(x)f_X(y) dy dx$. Using this you can compute $E[Z]$ and $Var(X)=E[Z^2]-E[Z]^2$, via 2D integrals, although there's no guarantee the answer has a nice closed form.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I will try if there is any way to approximate the real value since it might be hard to solve the integral. Thanks.

Comment: There's always numerical integration. Wolfram alpha can't solve by the integral for $E[Z]$ by finding antiderivatives but it does give $E[Z]\approx 0.958091$.

Comment: @Andrew Got it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $$\mathbb E\left[Z^2\right] = 2\mathbb E\left[X^2\right] = \frac2\pi\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm d x = \frac2\pi\int_{0}^1 u^{\frac12}(1-u)^{-\frac12}\mathrm d u = \frac2\pi B\left(\frac32, \frac12\right) = 1.$$

Second,

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[Z\right] &= \frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1 \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}\sqrt{1 - y^2}}\mathrm d x\mathrm d y\\
&\approx \frac4{n\pi^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n-1} \frac{\sqrt{k^2 + \ell^2}}{\sqrt{n^2 - k^2}\sqrt{n^2 - \ell^2}}
\end{align}

Comment: It's an insightful solution and the simulation result is close to that of the integral. Thanks.